# GStreamer rtsp pipeline freezes in cv2.VideoCapture , maybe related to audio channel

Tags: python-3.x, gstreamer, rtsp

I'm connecting with python+gstreamer to a DVR rtsp feed for image processing using opencv2. 
when using gstreamer pipelines on the cv2.VideoCapture the connection freezes (possibly waiting for a signal). The rtsp feed is made of h264 video (that I want to process) + pcma audio (which I want to discard).

Here is the function - it freezes on the cv2.VideoCapture line:

```
def simple_test2():
    rtsp_path = 'rtsp://admin:XXXX@10.0.0.50:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0'
    rtsp_path2 = 'rtspsrc location="{}" ! decodebin name=dcd dcd. ! videoconvert ! appsink max-buffers=1 drop=true dcd. ! audioconvert ! fakesink '.format(rtsp_path)
    logging.info('connecting to {} : {} '.format(cc['name'],rtsp_path2))
    vcap = cv2.VideoCapture(rtsp_path2)
    for i in range(2):
        logging.info('read frame #%s' % i )
        succ, frame = vcap.read()
        if succ:
            logging.info('%s  got frame %d : %s open? %s' % (cc['name'], i, str(frame.shape[0:2]),str(vcap.isOpened())))
        else:
            logging.info('%s fail frame %d open? %s' % (cc['name'], i,str(vcap.isOpened())))
        time.sleep(1)
    vcap.release()
```

Further investigation:

1) oddly enough - running the same pipeline in gst-launch works OK !

```
   gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location="rtsp://admin:XXXX@10.0.0.50:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=2&subtype=0" ! decodebin name=dcd dcd. ! videoconvert ! appsink max-buffers=1 drop=true dcd. ! audioconvert ! fakesink
```

return a steady stream of log messages coming in

2) If I use a simpler pipeline, in the code eg:

```
rtspsrc location="{}" ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! appsink max-buffers=1 drop=true
```

I end up getting connection error related to the fact the audio pad cannot be linked, which is why I tried using a fakesink to discard audio. other approaches will be appreciated

3) I also tried adding ! queue ! plugin in various places and combinations. nothing helps...